# Restart error "Failed to start LSB: Bring up/down networking" after configuring openvswitch with opennebula

Tags: networking, openvswitch, opennebula

I configured ovs-br0 openvswitch from physical port ens1f1, but then after restarting the network, I encountered an error Failed to start LSB: Bring up / down networking.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6bLrg.png)

## ip add

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYo8Q.png)

Please. Can you help me!

Answer (score 0):

Your server looks to be an RHEL/CentOS 7 one. Check if the file /etc/sysconfig/network exists on the server, if not just simply create one with touch command and try restarting or checking status post that.

```
touch /etc/sysconfig/network
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar after rebooting my CentOs 7.
First needed to see what was going on:

```
journalctl -u network.service
```

For me it was:

```
Bringing up interface enp2s0f0:  Error: Connection activation failed: No suitable device found for this connection (device eth0 not available because profile is not compatible with device (permanent MAC address doesn't match)).
```

Then I go to `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts` I noticed existence of some files like ifcfg-* , I deleted them, I have only left `ifcg-eth0`

Then I tried again

```
systemctl restart network
```

and it has started

```
 network.service - LSB: Bring up/down networking
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/network; bad; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Fri 2023-11-03 00:01:11 CET; 10min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
```